# How can I remap the numpad keys to select conversation responses?

Tags: dragon-age-origins, keyboard

In Dragon Age on the PC, the number keys (1, 2, 3, ...) are used to select responses during a conversation.

The numpad keys (the 0-9 keys on the right side of the keyboard) don't work for this, even with Num Lock turned on.  I don't see any options in the game's built-in "remap keys" menu to have the numpad keys do this.

Is there any way to remap the numpad keys to select conversation responses in Dragon Age?  Perhaps some configuration file can be edited?

Answer (score 2):

[Try GlovePIE](http://glovepie.org/glovepie.php)

It's a program that's actually used to map things like MIDI controllers, Wii-motes and PS3 controllers to actual keyboard commands, but naturally also works with regular keyboard remapping!

[image]

Note: It looks scary when you run it, but under **View** you can set it to GUI. There you can set it to Manual and change your Output Device to Keyboard. Then you just remap the regular 1-0 with your Numpad version.

Here's how the help file describes it:

> Start up PIE. Choose the "File" Menu,
>   then click "New". This will clear
>   whatever was in the big white box so
>   you can type your own script. We want
>   the W key to be controlled by the up
>   key so type this on one line then
>   press Enter:
>
> W = Up
>
> This is a working PIE Script so you
>   can test it by choosing the "Run!"
>   menu and clicking "Run".
>
> Whenever you press the up arrow key
>   (on the cursor pad, not the numeric
>   keypad) it will type a "w". Try it
>   out! This will work in any program.
>   Note that it will still move the
>   cursor up. The Up arrow key still has
>   its original function, but it emulates
>   a w at the same time. Try holding down
>   shift and pressing Up. It will type a
>   capital W, unless capslock is on.
>   Unlike the real "W" key, holding down
>   the Up arrow will only type a single
>   "w".
>
> Now chose the "Run!" menu and click
>   "Stop". This will return our keyboard
>   to normal.
>
> Now do the other keys like this:
>
> A = Left S = Down D = Right
>
> (Don't worry if the S is orange, that
>   is because S is also an abbreviation
>   for seconds).
>
> Save your script as Tutorial1.PIE by
>   chosing the "File" menu then "Save
>   As...". And run it again. Stop it when
>   you have finished playing.